# Troubles With React (Barely Starting to Learn It)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I was trying to start a list up in Scrimba with this code below:

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDom from "react-dom"

ReactDom.render(
  <ul>
    <li>Goanar</li>
    <li>Lam-Ruthadel</li>
    <li>Rambang</li>
 </ul>,
)
document.getElementbyId("root")
```

But it is showing "Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element. (/node_modules/fbjs/lib/invariant.js:42)"

What am I doing wrong? Is it how I wrote my code maybe? I've been stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ReactDom.render` is a method that takes two arguments and an optional callback, see the React docs for this method here: 
[ReactDom.render](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render)

So, in this scenario, if the method looks like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(element, container[, callback])
```

`element` will be your `<ul>...</ul>` and `container` is the documents "root" element: `document.getElementbyId("root")`

All together, it should look something like:

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDom from "react-dom"

ReactDom.render(
  <ul>
    <li>Goanar</li>
    <li>Lam-Ruthadel</li>
    <li>Rambang</li>
 </ul>,
 document.getElementbyId("root")
)
```

You should have a successful mount and render now. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You've most likely misplaced the closing parenthese:

```js
import React from "react"
import ReactDom from "react-dom"

ReactDom.render(
  <ul>
    <li>Goanar</li>
    <li>Lam-Ruthadel</li>
    <li>Rambang</li>
 </ul>,
 document.getElementbyId("root")
)
```

The target element is the second argument to `ReactDom.render()`.